# Box of theorem in RTL Languages In beamer

Tags: beamer, boxes, polyglossia

I would like to have both theorem enviroment English and RTL Language (arabic) which means the box of theorem would be in right side

```
\documentclass[hyperref={hyperfootnotes=false},10pt]{beamer}

%% to use arabic language and arabic fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Tahoma}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext=\beamer@framefootnotetext
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}


\begin{block}{Definition}
this is theorem in english version
\end{block}

\begin{block}{\textarabic{تعريف }}
this is theorem in arabic version which the left box will be in right side of the theorem enviroment
\textarabic{نص التعريف}
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{Theorem}
this is theorem in english version
\end{alertblock}

\begin{alertblock}{\textarabic{مبرهنة}}
\textarabic{محتوى}
\end{alertblock}

\begin{examples}{Example}
bla bla 
\end{examples}
\begin{examples}{متال}
\textarabic{متال}
\end{examples}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[hyperref={hyperfootnotes=false},10pt]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

%% to use arabic language and arabic fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext=\beamer@framefootnotetext
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{block}{Definition}
this is theorem in english version
\end{block}

{
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\begin{block}{\textarabic{تعريف }}
this is theorem in arabic version which the left box will be in right side of the theorem enviroment
\textarabic{نص التعريف}
\end{block}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but with box on title

Comment: Could you make fancy box

Comment: Could you hold English as the default language

Comment: @Educ Please have a look now